# Field extension splits into direct product of copies of splitting field

Tags: tensor-products

In *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by Mac Lane and Moerdijk, I read:

"Any field extension $K \rightarrow L$  has a splitting field $K \rightarrow N$ with $N$ normal. The fact that $N$ *splits* $L$ means that the tensor product (the coproduct) $L \otimes_K N$ is a direct product of copies of $N$; in elementary terms, if $L$ is given, say, as the field extension $L = K(\theta)$ generated by a root $\theta$ of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ in $K[x]$, a normal extension $N$ which splits $L$ will contain all the roots  $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n$ of the polynomial so that $L \otimes_K N \cong N[x]/(x-\theta_1)\dots(x-\theta_n) $ is just the product of $m$ copies of $N$.

I understand that a splitting field for a polynomial is an extension that contains all the roots. But my commutative algebra is too weak to follow the argument here. I don't understand why the isomorphism at the end holds and I don't understand why it can be decomposed into the product of copies of $N$. Additionally, are $L$ and $N$ being tensored as vector spaces over $K$ or as algebras?

Comment: $L$ is isomorphic to $K[X]/(f)$, hence $L\otimes _KN$ is isomorphic to $N[X]/(f)$: this is indeed basic commutative algebra (the tensor product "as algebras" is just the usual tensor product with its natural algebra structure). The question would be more appropriate on MSE.